# Android Chat room Application

Tags: android, android-emulator

Can anyone suggest me how to go forward (HOWTO guide/Steps) to create an android chatroom/chat application?
"Client-server app"
I am not able to start because I read something about jetty webserver but I couldn understand much how to start.
any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot for the help,
Rohit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look for XMPP information. You have great servers out there, free to use, like openfire, and client libraries for Android like asmack.